# Item passed correctly but the defineProps not receiving it correctly in Vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs

I have a chapter model and file model every chapter has many files
i added a button to add files , added the routes , controller and everything but i don't understand why the defineProps in the create vue is showing me the chapter as undefined but the url has the chapter id and everything so i think it's correct

the route:

```
Route::resource('files', FilesController::class)->only('store','create');
```

the add button with the link :

```
<Link :href="route('files.create', { chapter: chapter})">
  <button class="text-sm text-gray-500 font-semibold hover:underline hover:text-gray-700 mr-4">Add Files</button>
</Link>
```

the create vue :

```
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="upload">

    <input type="file" multiple name="files" @change="handleFileSelect"/>
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>

  </form>
</template>

<script setup>

import { useForm } from "@inertiajs/vue3";
const handleFileSelect = (event) => {
  form.filename = event.target.files[0].name;
};
const form = useForm({
    filename: "",
});

const upload = () => {
  form.post(route("files.store"), { chapter: chapter.value });
};
defineProps({
    chapter : Object,
})


</script>
```

the store function in the controller

```
    public function store(Request $request, Chapters $chapters)
    {


    if ($request->hasFile('files')) {
        foreach($request->file('files') as $file){
            $path = $file->store('files', 'public');
            $chapters->files()->save(new Files([
                'filename' => $path
            ]));
        }

    }
        return redirect()->back();
    }
```